# simple authentication using python panel holoviz

Tags: python, authentication, deployment, panel

I am happily deploying jupyter notebooks using the suggested command-line-interface
https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Deploy_and_Export.html

```
panel serve app.ipynb
```

How to add a simple username/password authentication?
I can not find anything on the official website...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to start right now (2020-5-14) is to look at the Bokeh documentation and example. You can find the example here https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/server_auth.

If you serve your app via `panel serve app.ipynb` that will work.

If you run your app via `python app.py` with `.show()` or `panel.serve` in the python file it will not work I believe.

There is a feature request on Github for auth documentation and that might contain updated information. See https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues/671